# How to convert vertical pandas table of 2 columns to horizontal table based on common ID value in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, transpose

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two'],
                    'bar': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C']})
```

|  | foo | bar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | one | A |
| 1 | one | B |
| 2 | one | C |
| 3 | two | A |
| 4 | two | B |
| 5 | two | C |

I would like to convert this to

| foo | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | A | B | C |
| Two | A | B | C |

And the code I tried is:

```
pd.pivot_table(df1,index='foo',aggfunc=['first'])
```

But the above code is returning only the first value

Answer (score 6):

We can enumerate groups with [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and use those as the pivot columns then [`add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) to the numerical values and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to return the 'foo' values to the columns:

```
new_df = (
    df1.pivot_table(index='foo',
                    columns=df1.groupby('foo').cumcount() + 1,
                    values='bar', 
                    aggfunc='first')
        .add_prefix('val')
        .reset_index()
)
```

```
   foo val1 val2 val3
0  one    A    B    C
1  two    A    B    C
```

---

See how `df1.groupby('foo').cumcount() + 1` makes the columns:

```
   foo  columns
0  one        1  # First instance of "one"
1  one        2  # Second instance of "one"
2  one        3  # Third instance of "one"
3  two        1
4  two        2
5  two        3
```

Code to generate the above DataFrame:

```
demo_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'foo': df1['foo'],
    'columns': df1.groupby('foo').cumcount() + 1
})
```

Comment: Hi @HenryEcker. I didn't know we can pass a Series as argument of `index` or `columns`. I used systematically `assign` before `pivot_table` to create a dummy index. Is it possible to do the same with `values` parameter?

Comment: @Corralien As far as I know, Series can only be directly passed to `index` and `columns`. It's for the same reason you can pass Series directly to `groupby` and `set_index`. Like `df1.set_index(['foo', df1.groupby('foo').cumcount() + 1])['bar'].unstack()` is roughly equivalent to `pivot_table` in this case. Or like [Scott Boston's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68536071/15497888) answer below passing the series directly to the `groupby` but the `values` argument is passed in the `[col label]` after. `set_index(...)[col].unstack()` so that can't be a `Series` only a label.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df1.groupby([df1.groupby('foo').cumcount() + 1,
             'foo']).first()['bar'].unstack(0).add_prefix('val').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   foo val1 val2 val3
0  one    A    B    C
1  two    A    B    C
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
x = df1.pivot("foo", "bar", "bar")
x.columns = [f"var{i}" for i in range(1, len(x.columns) + 1)]
x = x.reset_index()
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   foo var1 var2 var3
0  one    A    B    C
1  two    A    B    C
```

Comment: Interesting. This only works if bar values are unique though right?

Comment: @HenryEcker Yes, in that case probably `.drop_duplicates` is needed before.

Answer (score 0):

```py
pd.pivot_table(df1,index='foo',columns=df1.groupby(df1.foo).cumcount()+1,
               values='bar',aggfunc=(lambda x:min(x)), dropna=True).add_prefix('val')
```

output:

```py
    val1  val2  val 3
foo         
one   A     B     C
two   A     B     C
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a cue from @HenryEcker's solution, a combination of groupby and pivot can get the result:

```
(df1.assign(counter = lambda df: df.groupby('foo').cumcount())
    .pivot('foo', 'counter', 'bar')
    .rename(columns = lambda col: f"val{col}" if col!=0 else "val")
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
    val val1 val2
foo              
one   A    B    C
two   A    B    C
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two'],
                    'bar': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C']})
df1['i'] = df1['bar'].apply(lambda x: "val "+x)
pd.pivot(df1,index='foo',columns='i',values='bar')
```

Comment: Why? Be sure to offer an explanation of your code.